# Parsing a Text File and Assigning Values as Doubles in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I'm new to programming with Java so please bear with me. I have a large tab delimited text file that reads like so (but with many more numbers and characters):

> %Grid
>
> -50 -30 0 30 55
>
> -5 -3 0 3 5.5

I would like to be able to take the Max - Min values of each separate line underneath "%Grid" and assign those values as separate doubles. I am able to parse the very large file as an array which gives each value it's own row. Unfortunately though, I'm not sure what the code would look like for distinguishing between the rows that are in this text file. I have a piece of code that says

```
if (line.startsWith("%")){
}else {

}
```

which skips the lines that start with "%". After that I can't figure out how to get a Max-Min value from each separate row. Any help on showing me how to distinguish between rows in a text file or otherwise would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to split the parts of the line and then iterate through the array

```
double min;
double max;
String[] parts = line.split(" ");
for(String item : parts){
  min = (Double.isNaN(min) || min > Double.parseDouble(item) ? 
    Double.parseDouble(item) : min);
  max = (Double.isNaN(max) || max < Double.parseDouble(item) ? 
    Double.parseDouble(item) : max);    
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll try to implement this and update asap. Thanks a ton for your reply!